# Why is interactive command breaking when using zsh widget to execute it

Tags: shell, zsh

Zsh version:

zsh 5.4.2 (x86_64-ubuntu-linux-gnu)

The code(two files: .zshrc and interactive, both residing in my home directory):

.zshrc:

```
source ./interactive

custom_execute(){
  echo
  exc0 $BUFFER
  BUFFER=""
  zle accept-line
}
zle -N custom_execute
bind_enter(){
  bindkey '^M' custom_execute
}
```

interactive:

```
exc0(){
  echo exc0_begin
  cmd="$@"
  eval "$cmd"
  ret=$?
  echo exc0_end
  return $ret
}
```

Scenario:

Opening a new shell, execute the following command:

```
exc0 sudo apt remove gparted
```

It doesn't really matter what command is executed after exc0, the important thing is that it will need user input from stdin before it is finished. In my case, gparted is installed and it will ask me whether or not I want to remove it.

I use ctrl+c to terminate the command, since I don't really want to remove gparted.
The last line reads:

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] ^C%
```

Now I enter this command:

```
bind_enter
```

Afterwards:

```
sudo apt remove gparted
```

The last two lines show:

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
exc0_end
```

In both cases the shell asks for my sudo password, that part is working. But when it comes down to the confirmation, the second command breaks. Question: Why?

Comment: This isn't the cause of your immediate problem, but `cmd="$@"; eval "$cmd"` is generally buggy -- `"$@"` is an array, and can't be converted to a string without lossiness. To prove this to yourself, try running the following: `set -- printf '%s\n' "first line" "second line"; cmd="$@"; eval "$cmd"`

Comment: ...compare that to the correctly-functioning code `set -- printf '%s\n' "first line" "second line"; "$@"`, or the also-correctly-functioning `set -- printf '%s\n' "first line" "second line"; cmd=( "$@" ); "${cmd[@]}"`, or to the also-correctly-functioning `set -- printf '%s\n' "first line" "second line"; printf -v cmd '%q ' "$@"; eval "$cmd"`.

Comment: Anyhow, in terms of the difference between your `sudo` password and other input, use `</dev/tty` for any program you want to go to the TTY for input rather than using whatever stdin it happens to inherit.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I replaced eval "$@" with eval "$@" < /dev/tty. The problem is solved, although in my particular case I can't see the input as I type. Still helped me a ton, though, please consider writing an answer so I can accept.

Comment: It's still more correct as just `"$@" </dev/tty`, without the `eval`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If reads direct from the TTY (like `sudo` password entry) work, but reads from stdin (like regular prompts) don't, then you can work around this by redirecting the TTY to stdin for the specific commands that should be reading from the TTY.

Thus:

```
exc0() {
  local ret
  echo exc0_begin
  "$@" </dev/tty; ret=$?
  echo exc0_end
  return "$ret"
}
```

Note:

- The `</dev/tty` means that stdin is redirected from the TTY for the duration of the command in question.
- We flagged `ret` as a local variable to avoid polluting global namespace.
- We moved the assignment to `ret` to same the line as the command generating the exit status we want to capture (to make it less likely that future changes would be placed between the commands and thus modify `$?` without intent).
- We removed the unnecessary (and bug-inducing) use of `eval`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried using "$@" </dev/tty, but it says "exc0:4: command not found: sudo apt remove gparted". I would be happy to make it work without eval. Then, as I pointed out earlier, I can input text with this method, but do not see what I type. For a simple yes-no question that is OK, but I was testing "sudo -i -u postgres". Not seeing commands I type there is annoying. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Ahh! In that case, your code is being passed as a single argument, not one argument per word, so you could `eval "$1" </dev/tty` with the same effect.

Comment: As for seeing what you type, configuring local echo is a job for `stty`. Be sure you're giving it a file handle on `/dev/tty` to operate on.

Comment: I ended up saving the tty configuration I start with in my .zshrc and changing the eval line to eval "stty $STTY_CONFIG; $cmd" < /dev/tty. It's  working this way.